# Confusion on setting flags for yb-tserver in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am trying to set flag at yt-tserver startup:

```
--yb_enable_read_committed_isolation=true
```

But when checking in the console I see `--yb_enable_read_committed_isolation=false`.
How can I verify if the flag is used in the cli?
When trying to set flag using yb-ts-cli getting timeout error (firewall disabled):

```
$ ./bin/yb-ts-cli --server_address=192.186.56.71:9100 set_flag yb_enable_read_committed_isolation true
Unable to set flag: Network error (yb/rpc/yb_rpc.cc:549): Rpc timeout, passed: 15.000s, timeout: 15.000s, now: 2307.261s, last_read_time_: 2292.260s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual way to understand whether it's been set or not is to look at `http://<tserver ip>:<tserver port>/varz` for the value that `yb_enable_read_committed_isolation` is set to. It must be set identically on all servers.

If you want to test, here is a test case with multiple sessions:
https://dev.to/yugabyte/read-committed-is-a-must-for-postgres-compatible-distributed-sql-databases-59pf
Without read committed enabled, you will see serializable errors.
In general, better set the flags for all nodes , master and tservers, but this one is used only in tserver.